# Error creating new table in SQL Server 2014 Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I'm creating a new table and it throws an error continuously:

[image: picture]

While creating the new table i press left click so there is not any option of new table

Comment: Hint:  `CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: there is not any option to creat table

Comment: are yo able to open new query window ?

Comment: Does your login have the permission to create table the  database

Comment: yes Yashveer i can

Answer (score 0):

To create a new table first create a New Query, which is like a command you send to the server.

In the textbox write CREATE TABLE and choose an appropriate name.
Next you have to specify the columns in the table.

Heres an exmple below:

```
   SQL> CREATE TABLE CUSTOMERS(
       ID   INT              NOT NULL,
       NAME VARCHAR (20)     NOT NULL,
       AGE  INT              NOT NULL,
       ADDRESS  CHAR (25) ,
       SALARY   DECIMAL (18, 2),       
       PRIMARY KEY (ID)
    );
```

For more information visit this [website](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-create-table.htm).

Hope this helps

Comment: it's still not working it didn't show the new table written any where